# Mercurial merging default into named branch

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

I have a pretty simple Mercurial repo that has one named branch in addition to the `default` branch.

Changes have been made and committed to the `default` branch and I want to merge those into my named branch.  However, a `hg merge default` does not seem to be merging in all of the changes.

for example:

```
hg update working
99 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

hg status -m --rev default:working
```

there are about 20 files with modifications

```
M ... some list of files...
hg merge default
merging path/to/a/file/foo.java
3 files updated, 1 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)

hg status -m --rev default:working
```

Now there are *still* file with modifications that I would have expected to get merged.

I can do an `hg diff -r default` and see that there are changes that are not getting merged.

This is what the repo looks like

```
@  changeset:   4:d41da580b434
|  branch:      working
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      1:3ed1c8bf91cf
|  user:        bob costas
|  date:        Tue Mar 24 10:13:25 2015 -0500
|  summary:     pr-1243 and minor updates
|
| o  changeset:   2:ea0c249218fa
| |  parent:      0:385565af3c13
| |  user:        bob costas
| |  date:        Mon Mar 23 15:09:42 2015 -0500
| |  summary:     bunch of updated files and fixes
| |
o |  changeset:   1:3ed1c8bf91cf
|/   branch:      working
|    user:        bob costas
|    date:        Mon Mar 23 13:38:59 2015 -0500
|    summary:     pr-1231 
|
o  changeset:   0:385565af3c13
   user:        bob costas
   date:        Thu Mar 19 18:15:52 2015 -0500
   summary:     initial commit
```

Comment: Have you committed the merge changeset? (It isn't done automatically because you may have conflicts.)

Comment: Shouldn't the status command be: `hg status -m --rev default` (remove `:working` at the end)? Also is it possible that the differences you see with `hg diff` are actually changes made in the `working` branch that have not been merged to `default`? I'm not sure how you use those branches, but maybe you need to merge `working` into `default` before you merge the other way around.

Comment: @Edward  no, I have not yet committed the merge because I don't see that the merge is picking up all the required changes.

Comment: @DavidLevesque the status command works either way and both have identical results.  I added the `:working` just to be explicit about what revisions to compare.  There are changes in `working` that are not in `default`.  However, I am wanting to merge `default` into `working`, clean things up and then merge `working` into `default`.  I am 100% sure that there are changes in `default` (because I put them there) that are not in `working`, hence my need to merge.

Comment: If you compare the merged head with the `default` branch head, you should expect to see changes.  Specifically, you'll see changesets 1 and 4 (wait, what happened to 3?).  This is normal and what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't commit your merge.. Mercurial told you :

```
hg merge default
```

> merging path/to/a/file/foo.java 3 files updated, 1
>   files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved (**branch merge,
>   don't forget to commit**)

When you merge, all files stay modified in your sources, and you need to commit them

```
hg commit -m "merge with default"
```

Then your branch will appear merged in the log.